# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

[Screenshot of my error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhuqq.png)

My code always gets An unhandled exception of type '`System.NullReferenceException`' occurred in `mscorlib.dll`

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I am using `Visual Studio` and `performing async` await in mouse down event of a tile. Now I want to show message async from a user control which was inside a parent window.

I trace the error in comes from my declaration of the Metro Window. Hope you can help me solve this issue.

**Here is my code**:

```
        public async void tileLockUser_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dtgUserManagement.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            if (Convert.ToInt32(dtgUserManagement.SelectedValue) != 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dtgUserManagement.SelectedValue.ToString());
                var confirm = new MetroDialogSettings()
                {
                    AffirmativeButtonText = "YES",
                    NegativeButtonText = "NO"
                };

                MetroWindow metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);

                MessageDialogResult save = await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("CONFIRMATION", "DO YOU WANT TO LOCK USER?",
                                                                               MessageDialogStyle.AffirmativeAndNegative, confirm);

                if (save == MessageDialogResult.Affirmative)
                {
                    foreach (var row in dtgUserManagement.SelectedItems)
                    {
                        Membership user = db.Memberships.Find(dtgUserManagement.SelectedValue);
                        user.IsLockedOut = true;
                        user.LastLockedOutDate = DateTime.Now;
                    }
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    DataGridRefresh();
                    await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("USER", "Successfully locked!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("User restricted to be lock!", "User Management");
                await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("WARNING", "User restricted to be lock!");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Select use to lock", "User Management");
            await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("WARNING", "Select user to lock!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would add a breakpoint on the line where you create your MetroWindow then you can hover over each part of Application.Current.MainWindow to see which part is null. You can also use the Immediate or Locals windows when debugging to check variable values.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try and update you if it worked.

Comment: I tried about adding breakpoint. Each part of Application.Current.Maindow is not null but as whole it is null when it becomes MetroWindow.

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow` is not a `MetroWindow` thus the `metroWindow` variable is set to null and your next line where you are trying to call `ShowMessageAsync` will fail. You could try using the `is` keyword then hard casting using `(MetroWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow` but I suspect that will also fail.

Try calling the `GetType()` method on it to see what the underlaying type of `Application.Current.MainWindow` is then you can research how to cast (or construct) a `MetroWindow` from that.

Comment: Reference links: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/how-to-safely-cast-by-using-as-and-is-operators and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

From [this thread](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/issues/1022) it looks like if you remove

```
MetroWindow metroWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow);
```

and replace all occurances of `metroWindow` with the `this` keyword then it should work.

Comment: "this keyword" is not possible cause I am using user control.

Comment: Want to add a real cutdown version of your app to paste bin so that I can take a look. It’s a WPF app right?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44599691/8364643

Comment: Found it. Just like my question